# How would I make the fancybox lights out effect wider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

On my website [www.staygold-design.com](http://www.staygold-design.com) I have a fancybox jquery script on a button under the portfolio area. The button is "web designs." when I click that the fancybox does come up, but the problem is the lights out effect is all the way to the left.. I want it to cover my whole entire container div! What do I change to fix this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the horizontal layout of your site and (a design issue of fancybox v1.3.x.) the way the `viewport` is calculated.

As a workaround, after you loaded the fancybox css file, add this css inline declaration:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #fancybox-overlay {
   position: fixed !important;
 }
</style>
```